# How to access my Documents via Terminal on Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal

So every time I type `cd /Documents` it says

```
Users-MBP-4:~ user$ cd /Documents
-bash: cd: /Documents: No such file or directory
Users-MBP-4:~ user$
```

For some reason it only works when I type `cd /Applications`

I'm not too experienced with Using terminal on the Mac, any advice will help!

Answer (score 1):

Your documents are stored within your home directory, not at the root of the volume.

Try this instead:

`cd ~/Documents`

Answer (score 0):

The path should be:

```
cd /Users/YourUserName/Documents
```

Just substitute for YourUserName